Jest in a TypeScript monorepo
I'm working on a TypeScript monorepo and I'm trying to run Jest without the need to run yarn build in order to run yarn test.
If I run the application through tsx it runs perfectly (finding all the interdependencies), but I'm struggling with jest.
If I run yarn test without running yarn build I get this error:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/cicci/project/packages/utils/dist/cjs/index.js'

I tried:

running NODE_OPTIONS=--conditions=development yarn test;
adding testEnvironmentOptions: { customExportConditions: ['development'] } to jest.config.ts;
adding moduleNameMapper: { '@project/utils': __dirname + "../packages/utils" }, to jest.config.ts;
adding moduleNameMapper: { '@project/utils': __dirname + "../packages/utils/src" }, to jest.config.ts;
adding moduleNameMapper: { '@project/utils': __dirname + "../packages/utils/src/index.ts" }, to jest.config.ts;
adding modulePaths: ["../packages"], to jest.config.ts;
adding modulePaths: ["../packages/utils"], to jest.config.ts;
adding modulePaths: ["../packages/utils/src"], to jest.config.ts;

and several combinations of these, but the result is always:
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@project/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.

Do you have any other idea?

To run Jest tests without compiling .ts files to .js, you may use ts-jest library, which is a Jest transformer.
So you need to install it via command:
npm install --save-dev ts-jest

Then you need to to change preset field in jest config to ts-jest. If you don't have a config file, you may generate one:
npx ts-jest config:init

This will create a basic config, which will look like this:
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};

For other solutions you may check Jest documentation for TS integration

Thank you, but we use ts-jest ad we already have the said config in our jest.config.ts.

Do you mind providing it then? It may be the issue with the config itself
